# #nullable disable for a generated file?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm converting a C# codebase to enable `nullable` checks, but it contains one file that is generated by an external process and contains warning-emitting lines.  Because it's generated, if I add `#nullable disable`, that directive will get overwritten and lost.

Is there way to disable `nullable` checks for that file (or folder) from the .csproj file?

Comment: If this is code generated by something you control, you should look to include the <auto-generated/> comment tag to get VS/MSBuild to play nice with nullable warnings. If it is a third party code generator, check if they have an updated build or open issue around it, or try raising an issue with them to address marking generated files properly. Otherwise if OSS, consider implementing it with a pull request. Normally generated code is created using partial classes and you can extend them, but I did try adding a partial class with just the `#nullable disable` but that didn't work. (a pity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to mark code as "generated" so that code analysis ignores it. Unfortunately, most of them require you to have control over how the code is generated. If you cannot convince the people in charge of the code generator to use one of those approaches, the next-best thing is probably to use .editorconfig or .globalconfig to disable the analyzers for specific files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67592115/120955 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files

Comment: I tried that StackOverflow link already, but it didn't appear to do anything; does editorconfig only affect VS's static analysis rather than msbuild warnings?  That would be logical based on the name.

Comment: That would be logical, but the dotnet code analyzers actually do respect the .editorconfig file. There's probably a small detail somehow causing it not to work for you. You could also try .globalconfig files. See the second link I provided.